# Problem with DLC pack for Payday 2 PS4?

Tags: ps4, payday-2

I recently bought the $35 Payday DLC.  It mentioned new missions and items etc.  but when I play the game, I'm only seeing the few new missions that came with the patch already.

How do I access the DLC content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the new update came out for the consoles, I was confused as to what you get with the free update and what you need to pay for.  They also held the premium content for some days before releasing it to the marketplace.

Here is what is included in the premium DLC bundle (the one you have to buy):

- The Point Break Heists
- Yakuza Character Pack
- The Alesso Heist
- Gage Ninja Pack
- Butchers Western Pack
- The Golden Grin Casino Heist
- Sokol Character Pack
- The Butchers AK/Car Mod Pack
- Gage Chivalry Pack
- The BBQ Pack

Based on the price you listed in your question, it sounds like you bought the bundle for all the DLC.  If you have these items above, then your DLC is installed and ready. If for some reason you don't see these items, I would check you downloads on your PS4.  I know on Xbox One when you purchase something, sometimes you have to go into the games and apps section and tell it to install.

I belive in the FAQS section on the Overkill website it says if you do not have those heists DLCs, you can still join them and play them, you just cannot host/play them alone. The PC version of the game does this is well (this is actually why they allow for this on the consoles as well).

To double check if any of the heist DLCs were installed, attempt to purchase a contract (**do not search under the join heist option as for the reason above**) and see if any heists are written in red letters instead of blue. This means you don't have that DLC.

Check out [Overkills website](http://www.overkillsoftware.com/payday2/console) for more information.

Comment: I did buy the bundle; when I go to the individual items in the PS store they show as already purchased.  And I played the Alesso heist mission, so I guess I got everything.  I think I was expecting more missions (and for them to show up more often in crime.net) and a lot of it is stuff I probably won't use.  Oh well.  Thanks for confirming what's in the DLC for me though, that helps.